# Is there a cleaner way to parse my HTML data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I currently populate list boxes (amongst other things) by appending HTML. I get the PHP data from a JSON via an AJAX load, this allows me more flexibility on the page in terms of reloading things and cutting out unnecessary page loads.

```
function tracker_list(){
    //get a reference to the select element
    $list = $('#tracker_list');
    //remove entries
    $('#tracker_list').empty();
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data/JSON_dashboard.php',
      dataType:'JSON',
      success:function(data){ 
        //iterate over the data and append a select option
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
          $list.append('<li class="list-group-item"><div style="background: url(\''+val.profile_photo_path+'\');margin-right:10px;margin-left:7px" class="image-circle-30 pull-left"></div><span class="text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time timestamp pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="'+val.last_activity+'"></span></span><strong><a href="#">'+val.first_name+' '+val.last_name+'</a></strong> was on the <strong><a href="#">'+val.last_page+'</a></strong><br /><span class="text-muted small">'+val.since+'</span></li>'); 
          var total = val.total;
        $("#tracker_num").html("<strong>"+total+"</strong>");   // Replace total users number in head  
        })


      },
      error:function(){
      }
    });
    };
```

If I'm going to be continually doing this, is there a better way? As soon as I use a new line on all that HTML the script breaks and the code is going to start becoming quite unreadable.

Comment: For small snippets of HTML its fine. For larger chunks, I'd suggest using a templating library.

Answer (score 2):

For a cleaner and with more performance way.

HTML Manipulation for every element is expensive. Create an array, push into it, in the end join all items. And total count can be outside each iterate.

```
function tracker_list() {
    //get a reference to the select element
    $list = $('#tracker_list');
    //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/JSON_dashboard.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            //remove entries
            $list.empty();

            var strArr = [];
            //iterate over the data and append a select option
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                strArr.push('<li class="list-group-item"><div style="background: url(\'' + val.profile_photo_path + '\');margin-right:10px;margin-left:7px" class="image-circle-30 pull-left"></div><span class="text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time timestamp pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + val.last_activity + '"></span></span><strong><a href="#">' + val.first_name + ' ' + val.last_name + '</a></strong> was on the <strong><a href="#">' + val.last_page + '</a></strong><br /><span class="text-muted small">' + val.since + '</span></li>');
                .append();
            })

            $list.append(strArr.join(""));

            $("#tracker_num").html("<strong>" + data[data.length - 1].total + "</strong>"); // Replace total users number in head  

        },
        error: function() {}
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To add line breaks you can build the HTML in another var and add this to the HTML:

```
var html = '<li class="list-group-item"><div style="background';
html = html + 'url(\''+val.profile_photo_path+'\');margin-right';
html = html + '10px;margin-left:7px" class="image-circle-30 pull-left">';
// and so on...
$list.append(html)
```

Alternatively you can build the HTML with jQuery like this (only the first parts):

```
var html = $('<li />')
    .addClass('list-group-item')
    .append($('<div />')
        .css({
            background  : 'url('+val.profile_photo_path+')',
            marginRight : 10,
            marginLeft  : 7
        })
        .addClass('image-circle-30 pull-left')
    )
    .append($('<span />')
        .addClass('text-muted')
        .append($('<span />')
            .addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-time timestamp pull-right')
            .data({
                toggle  : 'tooltip',
                placement   : 'bottom'
            })
            .prop({
                title   : val.last_activity
            })
     );
  // and so on ...
  $list.append(html)
```

But I suggest you tu use a tempating engine like [JSRender](https://www.jsviews.com/) or [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a cleaner way to parse my HTML data?

Yes, that cleaner way is called HTML templating, for example with [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). You start off with writing the HTML part you need into a special script tag, with placeholders for the individual values you want to display.

```html
Total: <strong id="tracker_num"></strong>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="trackerlist-template">
  {{#each .}}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="profile-image" class="image-circle-30 pull-left" style="background-image: url('{{ profile_photo_path }}'); margin-right:10px; margin-left:7px;"></div>
    <span class="text-muted">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time timestamp pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{last_activity}}"></span>
    </span>
    <strong><a href="#">{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</a></strong> was on the
    <strong><a href="#">{{last_page}}</a></strong><br />
    <span class="text-muted small">{{since}}</span>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Then you can use that template in your JavaScript code and don't have to bother with HTML creation, because code and presentation are cleanly separated.

```
var trackerlistTemplate = Handlebars.compile( $("#trackerlist-template").html() );

function getTrackerList() {
    return $.get('data/JSON_dashboard.php').fail(function () {
        console.err("could not retrieve tracker list");
    });
}

function renderTrackerList(data) {
    $('#tracker_list').html( trackerlistTemplate(data) );
    $("#tracker_num").text(data.length);
}

$("#refreshButton").click(function () {
    getTrackerList().done(renderTrackerList);
});
```

Notes

- You don't need to use `$.ajax()` for such a simple GET request. `$.get()` is a lot shorter and will work just as fine.
- It might be useful to separate the function that fetches the data from function that works with the data. This can be achieved easily with jQuery, since you can return the XHR object from the data-fetching function and work with it elsewhere, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, this looks like exactly what I need to learn.

Comment: I have an issue... I've installed handlebars.js, after trying a quick example I can confirm handlebars is installed and working. However, when using the code you provided I get nothing... I've checked the console and there are no errors. However, when clicking a simple button to refresh the data, I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: trackerlistTemplate.render is not a function

Comment: You are right, there is no `render`, my mistake. You can simply call the template with the data (`trackerlistTemplate(data)`) to have it rendered. I strongly recommend reading the [getting started](http://handlebarsjs.com/#getting-started) section of the documentation, you could have spotted that yourself. ;)